# How to display "»" \xBB in xterm?

Tags: xterm, character-set

I am trying to display double > "»". I belive it is xBB in char set. How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Typing or displaying?

Answer (score 2):

The `»` character is the Unicode character [`U+00BB`](http://unicode-table.com/en/00BB/);

You may print it using its Unicode code point (in `bash` 4.2+) or its UTF-8 hexadecimal representation using `echo`:

```
user@debian ~ % echo -e '\u00BB' 
»
user@debian ~ % echo -e '\xC2\xBB'
»
```

Or using `printf`:

```
user@debian ~ % printf '%b\n' '\u00BB'
»
user@debian ~ % printf '%b\n' '\xC2\xBB'
»
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works.  
Question: what the \u00 means and what different from \x00\xC2?  Why it works on  other term type by just using \xBB?

Comment: @linux-lover Actually my answer was rather unprecise, for various reasons; see the update. The `\uNNNN` sequence is directly interpreted as an Unicode code point (this works only in `bash` 4.2+), while *I guess* that the `\xC2\xBB` sequence is interpreted based on the shell's current encoding. Where did you type `\xBB` to get `»`?. Anyway I'd like to tell more about the second option, but in total honesty I just know that it works. Gonna do some research tomorrow tough, since I'm interested as well, and I'll update this answer as well.

Comment: Sorry, did not response immediately. Your suggestions work on both method. I use \xBB to get >> on command prompt for many years from old version putty (NOT 2015-09-02.1e0e962) to linux (Oracle, Red hat and SuSe).  Now, I have to use your suggestion.